# an Apache Ant task to generate phar packages?

Tags: php, eclipse, ant, phar

I'm moving my php projects to phar packages and while Eclipse (I'm using e4.1) generates phars nicely, I have a problem with updating project's deployment ant scripts accordingly...

**NOTE**: *I don't want to use ant's exec to call operating system's php runtime to do that. I cannot always rely on it to be there...*

A. Is there an ant task which can generate phar packages?

B. Is there a way to call Eclipse's phar export task headlessly?

C. Is there a way to execute php script by ant using eclipse's php runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The [manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php):

> Phar archives can be distributed as
>   tar archives, zip archives, or as the
>   custom phar file format designed
>   specifically for the phar extension.
>   Each file format has advantages and
>   disadvantages. The tar and zip file
>   formats can be read or extracted by
>   any third-party tool that can read the
>   format, but require the phar extension
>   in order to run with PHP. The phar
>   file format is customized and unique
>   to the phar extension, and can only be
>   created by the phar extension or the
>   PEAR package » PHP_Archive, but has
>   the advantage that applications
>   created in this format will run even
>   if the phar extension is not enabled.

So you can just zip some files up and name the resulting file `.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's PHP runtime is also a php executable that is located deeply in a plugin folder.